# Group columns and sum values in R

Tags: r

I have a data set which looks like this

```
Variable    A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3  
Item 1  Men 1   3   3   1   2   3
Item 2  Men 1   3   3   1   2   3
Item 1  Men 1   3   3   1   2   3   
Item 3  Men 2   1   2   5   3   3
Item 2  Men 1   3   3   1   2   3
```

I need to group columns `A1, A2, A3` to be `A` and  `B1,B2,B3` to be `B`, thereafter I would like to sum the values.

How do I do this in R ?

Answer (score 2):

If you only have to do this for a few variables, you could do:

```
df$A <- rowSums(df[grep("^A\\d+$", names(df))])
df$B <- rowSums(df[grep("^B\\d+$", names(df))])
df[!names(df) %in% grep("^[A-Z]{1}\\d+$", names(df), value = TRUE)]
df
#  Variable Sex A  B
#1   Item_1 Men 7  6
#2   Item_2 Men 7  6
#3   Item_1 Men 7  6
#4   Item_3 Men 5 11
#5   Item_2 Men 7  6
```

(I called the "MEN" column Sex since it seemed like there were too few column names).

The `grep()` command I wrote above uses regular expressions. For example, `"^A\\d+$"` matches those column names that start with "A" followed by any number of digits. The `grep` command returns the indices where those matches were found (in the column names) and therefore the `rowSums` will only add up the right columns.

A very similar concept is used in the third line to drop the columns which are of the format: Any *single* capital letter (A to Z) followed by any number of digits, will be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

```
test.df$A <- test.df$A1 + test.df$A2 + test.df$A3
```

and the same for B. This code will just create a new variable in your dataframe named A with the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `many` groups, you could convert the `wide` format to `long` format and then do the necessary calculation.  Here is one way using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df$indx <- 1:nrow(df)

df %>% 
   gather(Var, Val, -Variable,-indx) %>%
   extract(Var, c('Var1', 'Var2'), '(.)(.)') %>% 
   group_by(Variable, indx, Var1) %>%
   summarise(Val=sum(Val)) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   spread(Var1, Val) %>% 
   arrange(indx)

#     Variable indx A  B
#1 Item 1  Men    1 7  6
#2 Item 2  Men    2 7  6
#3 Item 1  Men    3 7  6
#4 Item 3  Men    4 5 11
#5 Item 2  Men    5 7  6
```

Or another option would be to use `Map` with `rowSums`

```
 indx <- sub('\\d+', '', colnames(df)[-1])
 lst <- split(colnames(df)[-1],indx)
 df1 <- df[1]
 Un <- unique(indx)
 df1[Un] <- Map(function(x,y) rowSums(x[y], na.rm=TRUE),
                                                     list(df), lst)
 df1
 #     Variable A  B
 #1 Item 1  Men 7  6
 #2 Item 2  Men 7  6
 #3 Item 1  Men 7  6
 #4 Item 3  Men 5 11
 #5 Item 2  Men 7  6
```

Or if the columns are `ordered` ie. `A1, A2,A3` followed by `B1, B2, B3` etc. and the number of columns per each group is the same. (Change the `dim` accordingly)

```
 df1[Un] <- apply(array(as.matrix(df[-1]), 
                              dim=c(nrow(df),3,length(Un))), c(1,3), sum)
```

#### data

```
df <-  structure(list(Variable = c("Item 1  Men", "Item 2  Men", "Item 1  Men", 
"Item 3  Men", "Item 2  Men"), A1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), A2 = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L), A3 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), B1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 1L), B2 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L), B3 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
)), .Names = c("Variable", "A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```